# Как не отображать элемент который начинает обрезаться при скролле?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Чтобы если элемент начинает скрываться то он не отображался. Можно ли это сделать чисто на css?
2. Возможность чтобы скролл выполнялся с определенным интервалом, то есть по строкам, а не пикселям? Тогда строку не нужно будет скрывать.

Comment: Не отображался - т.е. `opacity:0`? Или `display:none`? Могли бы воспроизводимый код написать

Comment: opacity.
Да просто div блок внутри div.

Comment: Дело не в сложности кода, а в Вашем отношении, Вы же не новичек... как-то так

Comment: По сути, как это сделать только на css - не знаю. На JS, Вам поможет  Intersection_Observer - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API .

Comment: Похоже то что надо

Answer (score -1):

```css
 p.clip {
    white-space: nowrap; /* Запрещаем перенос строк */
    overflow: hidden; /* Обрезаем все, что не помещается в область */
    background: #fc0; /* Цвет фона */
    padding: 5px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* Добавляем многоточие */
   }
```

```html
<p class="clip">Магнитное поле ничтожно гасит большой круг небесной сферы, 
  в таком случае эксцентриситеты и наклоны орбит возрастают.</p>
```

1. Взял отсюда http://htmlbook.ru/css/text-overflow

Comment: Тут решение не связано со скроллом.